# Was OMAP3 support dropped for 12.04?

Tags: arm, 12.04

The omap3 images was deleted from the cdimages yesterday. Was it dropped or is the OMAP4 identical to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some problem with Annonaceae buildd and it should be fixed now.
See http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/11/14/%23ubuntu-arm.txt